# Capturing Range Values in a VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba, function, range

I am "painting" a single-column data range (called "myRange") as a function argument. The function is called "myFunction".    I would like to, for example, output the third value from the range. In general, I need to access specific values from the input range. The code below does not work.

```
Function myFunction(myRange As Range)

 myFunction = myRange(3).Value

End Function
```

My guess is the solution is pretty easy, but I am missing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If I understand correctly, there are multiple approaches which you can use. As indicated in [Range object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)), changing `myRange(3)` to `myRange.Cells(3,1)` is one way that should work. This is because, since the range is of a single-column data range, this is stating to use the cell that is in row 3 and column 1 relative to the upper-left hand corner of your range.

Comment: Define the "third value"?  What if the range spans rows and columns?  Do you go down or across to find the third value?

Comment: Why do you think `The code below does not work`? What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to `Cells` as said in first comment.

```
Function myFunction(myRange As Range) As Variant
    ' here we will check if the range contains at least 3 cells
    If myRange.Cells.Count >= 3 Then
        ' if yes we access the third cell
        myFunction = myRange.Cells(3, 1).Value
    Else
        ' else we can't access it because this does not exist
        myFunction = 0
    End If
End Function
```